# Clone works just once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with class item that I want to clone as many times as the user click on a div with add id

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="clone">clone me</div>
<div id="add">add</div>
```

And here is my JavaScript code

```
$(function(){
    var request = $('.clone').clone();
    $('.clone:last').addClass('test'); // i don't want my new div have the new added class test just clone
    $('#add').click(function () {
        console.log('clicked');
        request.insertAfter($('.clone:last'));

        // $('.item:last').after(request); // this doesn't work as well
    });
});
```

it print to the console clicked as many times as I click on add

But doesn't clone the div more than once

i will be making changes to clone div that don't wanna be done to the new ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `request` refers to same element, move it inside the `click` handler. Also use `:first` selector to select the first element.

*Use*

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  //Create then object the click handler
  var request = $('.clone:first').clone();
  request.insertAfter($('.clone:last'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clone">clone me</div>
<div id="add">add</div>
```

---

If you don't want changes to the original one to affected the new one. Create object as you have created originally. However create a `clone()` before using `.insertAfter()`

```js
var request = $('.clone:first').clone();
$('#add').click(function() {
  request.clone().insertAfter($('.clone:last'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clone">clone me</div>
<div id="add">add</div>
```

Comment: no if i changed the original one the new one will be affected

Comment: it works now all i missed was additional clone thanks dude :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the `request` inside the function, so that it clones again and again. Right now the `request` contains only one element and if you are inserting it after (which it is  already), there's no effect:

```
$(function(){
    $('#add').click(function () {
        var request = $('.clone').clone().removeClass("clone");
        console.log('clicked');
        request.insertAfter($('.clone:last'));

        // $('.item:last').after(request); // this doesn't work as well
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There're 2 issue:

1. You have to put `var request = $('.clone:first').clone();` inside.
2. You need to clone only `first` div so use `$('.clone:first').clone()`.

Here you go:

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    var request = $('.clone:first').clone();
    console.log('clicked');
    request.insertAfter($('.clone:last'));
});
```

[JS FIddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/o0rc1eqt/12/)

Comment: What did you added?

Comment: read the question please i don't wanna clone it after the change only before

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do same thing without clone.

```
$(function(){
    var request = $('<div class="clone">clone me</div>');
    $('#add').click(function () {
        console.log('clicked');
        request.insertAfter($('.clone:last'));

    });
});
```

Comment: @robert Yes, always. its so easy and simple solution. I will recommend to use this.